# Option Base image does not appear in magento admin

Tags: php, magento, adminhtml

I'm having a problem where the option of Base image does not appear in magento admin, anyone has any idea what can be?

look:
[image: image example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and verify you have the "Base Image" labeled attribute. if its missing you must add this attribute, and drag it into the attribute set for the product in which its missing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and verify you have the "Base Image" labeled attribute.Then click the attribute and select option Apply To * -> All products type. Because sometime you have used any product related extension that will be automatically select particular product type.